# How to set the global locale in a Yii application

Tags: php, yii, locale

What it the correct way to set the global PHP locale in a Yii application?

I've managed to find that locale is set in PHP with setlocale() function. But where should I put its call to be applicable for the entire Yii Web application?

Note that I want to set the same specific PHP locale for all parts of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set from index.php

In our apps we define APPLICATION_ENV in index.php and use it anywhere..

```
define("APPLICATION_ENV", "production");
```